# Mysql - How to query a column for duplicates values but have different values in a different column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Id  Email   Unsubscribed
1   email_1 0
2   email_2 0
3   email_3 1
4   email_1 1
5   email_4 1
6   email_3 0
7   email_1 0
8   email_4 1
```

I am trying to query for all duplicate emails that have different values in the Unsubscribed column. I want to return something like this based on the above example:

```
Email
email_1
email_3
```

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT etc.

Comment: the result email1 and email4 i would understand but why email3 ?

Comment: I wouldn't want email4 because it has the same Unsubscribed value in all instances.  I would want email3 because it has varying values for Unsubscribed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It think you just want this:

```
SELECT Email
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Email
HAVING MIN(Unsubscribed) <> MAX(Unsubscribed);
```

The `HAVING` clause would only assert to true if a given email appeared with more than one value for unsubscribed.